# Oracle SQL - convert select count(*) into zero or one

Tags: sql, oracle, count, binary, boolean

I'm using Oracle and I want to turn the result from a select count into a "binary" 0/1 value ... 0 = 0 ... non-zero = 1.  From what I read online, in MS SQL, you can cast it to a "bit" but Oracle doesn't appear to support that.

Here's my simple example query (the real query is much more complex). I want MATCH_EXISTS to always be 0 or 1. Is this possible?

```
select count(*) as MATCH_EXISTS 
from MY_TABLE 
where MY_COLUMN is not null;
```

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza -- It is that magic time on friday when all DBAs declare the work week done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should be fastest... get at most one row.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS MATCH_EXISTS
FROM MY_TABLE 
WHERE MY_COLUMN IS NOT NULL
  AND rownum <= 1;
```

Comment: You beat me, but why you need rownum?

Comment: because you don't want count(*) to be greater than 1 and it will be fast.  Stops when it finds the first non-null

Comment: (Deleted previous comment, this works nicely, I was just testing wrong.)

Comment: @hvd - at most one NON NULL row.  There is a where.

Comment: Bravo!  This is really slick.  I never would have though to use the rownum as a constraint on the where clause to get the results I want.

Comment: @Hogan...   This code is part of a much larger query with multiple nested selects.  If there's any concerns about using rownum, I would happily use a solution using EXISTS instead.

Comment: @krick - no concerns if you are using Oracle. As Gordon says they both do exactly the same thing. My answer is easier to read and understand (which is why it got more votes IMO). Gordan's answer will work on all platforms (which is why I said it was better). Use the one that make sense to you -- they are both the same even in a complicated query

Answer (score 1):

If you use an `exists` clause this should be faster for large tables because Oracle doesn't need to scan the whole table. As soon as there is one row, it can stop retrieving it:

```
select count(*) as match_exists
from dual
where exists (select * 
              from my_table 
              where my_column is not null);
```

Comment: rownum like my example will be faster -- only one select not two.

Comment: @Hogan: this will also select only _one_ row from `my_table`. The "counting" on `dual` is essentially "free"

Comment: but not totally free :)

Comment: @Hogan: I don't think you will be able to measure that.

Comment: hey if it makes the execution plan longer then it counts!

Answer (score 1):

Don't do a `count()`.  For performance, use `exists`:

```
select (case when exists (select 1 as MATCH_EXISTS 
                          from MY_TABLE 
                          where MY_COLUMN is not null
                         )
              then 1 else 0
        end)
from dual;
```

This can be significantly faster.

Comment: don't you think mine would be faster where result = 1?

Comment: @Hogan Looks like the `exists` will work exact to your `rownum <=1`

Comment: @Hogan . . . No, I don't think yours would be faster.  They would probably both have the same plan.  However, for complicated queries, I trust the optimizer to consistently choose the best plan for `EXISTS` over `rownum`.

Comment: `EXISTS` is also much more portable.  So your answer is probably better in general.  I'm just shocked -- this is the first time my answer got selected over both you and horse.  I might have to retire now.  Achievement unlocked.

Comment: @Hogan . . . Yours is clever.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CASE WHEN`:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN MATCH_EXISTS = 0 THEN 0
            ELSE 1
       END AS MATCH_EXISTS 
FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS MATCH_EXISTS 
      FROM MY_TABLE 
      WHERE MY_COLUMN IS NOT NULL) AS t;
```

**EDIT:**

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 0 THEN 0
            ELSE 1
        END as MATCH_EXISTS 
FROM MY_TABLE 
WHERE MY_COLUMN IS NOT NULL;
```